# Netbeans - one maven project as denepdency for another

Tags: maven, netbeans

I have two maven projects in Netbeans. How can I add one as dependency for another?

In Intellij IDEA I can just add `<dependency>` and it works fine. But Netbeans can't resolve this dependency this way.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so, in Netbeans. Just make sure to have the project, you want to use as dependency, is built into your maven-local-repo by executing a maven-install.

I don't know how it works in Netbeans, but in Eclipse you can just `Rightclick -> Run as-> Maven Install` to install your project.

Maybe in Netbeans, you have to use the Maven-cmd-tool. Just navigate to the location in your project, where your `pom.xml` is, and run `mvn install`. That should install your project into your maven-local-repo. After that, just run `mvn clean install -U` in your other project, which uses the previously built project as dependency, and it should recognize the dependency.